# What spreadsheets import from my spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Is it possible to get a list of the spreadsheets that are importing data from my sheet?

I maintain a spreadsheet that has raw data, and many other spreadsheets use IMPORTRANGE to import that data.

I need to update the structure of the original sheet, and would like a list of all the spreadsheets that depend upon it.  Is there a way to find this out?

Comment: Are you using a common Google account or a G Suite account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature that list the spreadsheets that use IMPORTRANGE to import data from a specific spreadsheet.

Considering that IMPORTRANGE to your spreadsheet could be added to any spreadsheet that any editor, viewer and commenter of your spreadsheet have access even if you don't have access to them, I think that there is no way to have a complete list other than asking those users to give you that information even manually or by running a script.

Comment: Thank you, Rubén.  I just realized that I can use Tools > Activity Dashboard to see who has viewed the sheet and are the most likely people who need to be informed about the upgrades.

Comment: @MichaelLeahy it's worthy to note that the Activity Dashboard is only available for G Suite accounts.